# How to control pagination in laravel-dompdf?

Tags: css, laravel, pagination, pdf-generation, dompdf

So, I am generating a PDF file through my Laravel project using the laravel-dompdf package.

Everything is going well but I need to start paginating after the content table is created. This means, start paginating from page 3 or 4 depending on how big the PDF gets.

I am currently doing this with CSS using the `content` property, but this paginates every page starting with the first one. Any ideas?

```
#footer .page:before
{
    content: "Page " counter(page);
}
```